# PGError: ERROR: syntax error at or near E'String'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Ruby on Rails condition that works in MySQL but not in PostGres

```
:conditions => ["A between ? and ? and B between ? and ? and C between ? and ? and ddd is ?",@amin,@amax,@bmin,@bmax,@cmin,@cmax,params[:input].to_s]
```

Generates the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "E'word'"
LINE 1: ...c between -100 and 100 and ddd is E'word')
```

I know that it works without the last comparison. Eg.

```
    :conditions => ["A between ? and ? and B between ? and ? and C between ? and ?",@amin,@amax,@bmin,@bmax,@cmin,@cmax]
```

ddd is of type :string whereas a,b and c are all :decimal.

After doing some research on Postgresql it seems that E' Strings are escaped strings - this doesn't help me as I can't seem to correct it. I don't work with the Postgresql very often so I apologize in advance if it is something obvious.

I'm using heroku for hosting so I can't change any Postgresql settings. Anyway, I'd prefer to really understand what the problem is and how to fix it.

Cheers,
Stu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
ddd is ?
```

into

```
ddd = ?
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [`IS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html) operator cannot be used for comparing text values. What was your intention for it?

Comment: I am using 'is' as it keeps it readable and works in MySQL, but I could use the = operator just as easily. I'll try that - cheers for the tip.

Comment: It doesn't work in MySQL in your situation, it's a boolean operator and not a string operator: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is It's a bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried and ddd = ?  as opposed to is?

```
 :conditions => ["A between ? and ? and B between ? and ? and C between ? and ? and ddd = ?",@amin,@amax,@bmin,@bmax,@cmin,@cmax,params[:input].to_s]
```